# python encode the defined variable from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

how to get the the text itself from a txt file in python 3?
so, I've a file that contains string like that:

```
"name":"\u0414\u043e\u0436\u0434\u044c"
```

The code I wrote is:

```
with open(r'C:\Temp\f1.txt','r') as f1:
    data=f1.read()
f1.close()
#print(data)
f2 = open(r'C:\Temp\f2.txt','w+',encoding='utf-8')
f2.write(data)
f2.close()
```

I wonder why the data var is not 'utf-8' encoded?

if I write like so:

```
var = '"name":"\u0414\u043e\u0436\u0434\u044c"'
print(var)
```

everything is goin well. the output data is a text

Comment: What makes you think it's not encoded? In what way is everything going well?

Comment: When you use ``with open() as f1`` you do not need to call ``f1.close()``.

Comment: I mean i need to get the text rather than unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 it's a little trickier, you have to convert the string to bytes first and then decode it:

```
bytes(var, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Since you have the text stored in a file, you can read the file in binary mode. Then it is cleaner:

```
with open(r'C:\Temp\f1.txt', 'rb') as f:
    var = f.read()

var.decode("unicode-escape")
```